# How do I stop my viewmodel from being created in my db with entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I created a viewmodel class in a folder where my other app entities reside. What do I need to do to stop entity framework from creating tables with my viewmodels in the db?

Comment: Create a separate folder for view models.

Comment: I did that...In my assembly I have a folder called models, which has all my entities and I have another folder called ViewModels which has my viewmodels.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there was some auto generated code in my dbcontext class that added stuff from my viewmodels. I commented it out and it now works without creating viewmodel entities in my db.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I recommend you to use this VS2015 feature to easily find out where is your ViewModel referenced and remove it:

[image: view model usage]